# xontrib autojump freezes xonsh shell

Tags: python-3.x, shell, xonsh

I'm using MiniConda with xonsh installed.
Running print(sys.version) produces:

```
3.7.4 (default, Aug  9 2019, 18:34:13) [MSC v.1915 64 bit (AMD64)]
```

I'm not sure which version of xonsh I'm using, but I installed it yesterday (Jan 29, 2020) and it's whatever the conda command got.

When I run `xontrib list` I get

```
apt_tabcomplete     not-installed  not-loaded
autojump            installed      not-loaded <======= NOTE!
autovox             installed      not-loaded
autoxsh             not-installed  not-loaded
avox                not-installed  not-loaded
bashisms            installed      not-loaded
base16_shell        not-installed  not-loaded
coreutils           installed      not-loaded
direnv              not-installed  not-loaded
distributed         installed      not-loaded
docker_tabcomplete  not-installed  not-loaded
free_cwd            installed      loaded
```

The key point being that autojump *is* installed, but it is *not* loaded.

When I run `xontrib load -v autojump` I get a single message, and then the shell freezes up (the cursor is still blinking, but the shell isn't doing anything).  The message is:

```
loading xontrib 'autojump'
```

I'm taking care to use the Python stuff from the MiniConda install (not my other copies of Python that I've got).

Would anyone have any ideas about how to debug this?  I'd love to find a way to get more information about what's going on and why it's freezing.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try to load `autojump` with `THREAD_SUBPROCS=True` in `.xonshrc`:

```py
with ${...}.swap(THREAD_SUBPROCS=True):
  xontrib load autojump
```

Or in xonsh >= 0.9.23 with shorter alternative:

```
$THREAD_SUBPROCS=True xontrib load autojump
```